# Resource leak using mopub

Tags: android, mopub

I'm using mopub interstitial. Everything looks fine but I keep seeing:

```
Explicit termination method 'close' not called
        at dalvik.system.CloseGuard.open(CloseGuard.java:184)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:78)
        at com.mopub.common.DiskLruCache.get(DiskLruCache.java:424)
        at com.mopub.common.CacheService.containsKeyDiskCache(CacheService.java:77)
        at com.mopub.mobileads.util.vast.VastManager.updateDiskMediaFileUrl(VastManager.java:105)
        at com.mopub.mobileads.util.vast.VastManager.onAggregationComplete(VastManager.java:74)
        at com.mopub.mobileads.util.vast.VastXmlManagerAggregator.onPostExecute(VastXmlManagerAggregator.java:66)
        at com.mopub.mobileads.util.vast.VastXmlManagerAggregator.onPostExecute(VastXmlManagerAggregator.java:18)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

This happens only if I load the interstitial and with the following steps:

1. open the app
2. the activity with the interstitial is created
3. the interstitial is created and its loading starts
4. `onInterstitialLoaded` is called
5. put the app in the background
6. the activity is killed
7. bring the app to the foreground
8. the activity is restored
9. the app "leaks"

I call the destroy of the interstitial in the `onDestroy` of the activity

Do you know what I might be missing to get this problem?

Comment: Hey Herschel,

Looking into the source code of the MoPub SDK, it looks like the http client isn't being closed.

https://github.com/mopub/mopub-android-sdk/blob/master/mopub-sdk/src/main/java/com/mopub/mobileads/util/vast/VastXmlManagerAggregator.java#L55

What MoPub Android SDK version are you using?

Comment: Thank you @Edward. I'm using the version 3.4.0.